# Application Freezes when making URL requests

Tags: wxpython

I m making a small application, where I POST some parameters with urllib2 to 8 different sites, with command line Interface, its works fine, but same thing when i use with wxPython, the Application freezes and shows not responding. the same thing happened when i used to read some files, but I overcame it for reading files with wx.Yield(), but it seems wx.Yield() is not working for URL requests.

I am using BOA constructor for constructing the frame.

In gist the program is like this:

```
def buildURL(url, params):
    #url built here 
    return url



def url1(self, value):
    #self.buildURL(url, params)
    #makes the request
    #searches if there was a valid response
    #if yes, show it to txtCtrl2

#same for url2 to url8

def onClickCheck(self, event):
    #get the value from txtCtrl1
    #Do the required things
    AppUrlLibrary = [self.url1(value)...self.url8(value)]
    for i in AppUrlLibrary:
        if self.abort:
            break
        else:
            wx.Yield() #this seems not working
            i
```

I need some help on this, I strongly believe that, my coding structure is wrong! I need some guide.

All Displays And Responses are sent to txtCtrl2.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you are doing is blocking the GUI's mainloop. In other words, it's a long running task. That means you'll probably need to use threads, queues or similar to get around this. There are 3 thread-safe methods: wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent. If you try to talk to your GUI without using one of those from a thread, then you'll have issues. There's several examples on the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) or you can read my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/).

Comment: Thanks for responding.. i will check the tutorials.. i tried googling around but did not find proper example.. i will check with yours :)